# How to summarize data based on unique ID in R

Tags: r, analytics, analysis, modeling

I have a very large data set with about 3000 observations and 121 variables.  Each observation contains information about a phone call.  Each device has a unique IMEI and there are duplicate IMEI's in the dataset because one device could have multiple phone calls.

This data was originally in JSON format in multiple files.  Each row was a separate file so I used this script to import the JSON objects using the jsonlite pckg and then used rbind to bind them all together into one large matrix, which I then converted into a data frame using the as.data.frame() function.

```
    require(jsonlite)
    files <- list.files()
    DF <- NULL

    for (f in files) {

        DF <- rbind(DF, fromJSON(f))
     }

    DF<- as.data.frame(DF)
```

But, I want to summarize the data based on each UNIQUE IMEI.

For example:

IMEI 123456789 has 10 entries with variables call_duration, signal_strength, battery_level.  I'd like to summarize the 10 entries into one entry summing call_duration, and averaging signal_strength and battery_level, so the result would be:

```
   IMEI    call_duration(sum) signal_strength(mean) battery_level(mean)`

123456789     1982                    65               42
```

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: You could try `library(data.table); setDT(df1)[, list(call_duration=sum(call_duration), signal_strength=mean(signal_strength), battery_level=mean(battery_level)), by=IMEI][]`

Comment: thanks for the input but I get an error saying:
The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1

Comment: You should provide some lines of your dataset that gives the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tapply to calculate the mean (or sum):

```
call_durationSUM <− tapply(X=DATA$call_duration, INDEX=DATA$IMEI, sum)
signal_strengthMEAN <− tapply(X=DATA$signal_strength, INDEX=DATA$IMEI, mean)
battery_levelMEAN <− tapply(X=DATA$battery_level, INDEX=DATA$IMEI, mean)
```

And then cbind them together.

Comment: Hello thanks for your suggestion.  I tried it and got the following error:
Error in tapply(X = DF$avg_speed, INDEX = DF$imei, mean) : 
  arguments must have same length

Comment: I;ve added some lines of code to my original post regarding how i got the data.

Comment: Hmm, vectors in a df should have equal length. Are you sure you spelled the names correctly? (otherwise one vector has length 0).

Answer (score 1):

Both tapply and data.table are useful commands to use. Another possibility is to use the sqldf package and enter SQL commands as follows:

```
# install.packages('sqldf') # If not already installed
# options(gsubfn.engine = "R") # needed for older version of R. Most will not need this

library(sqldf)
info <- sqldf('select IMEI, sum(call_duration) as sum_call_duration, 
    avg(signal_strength) as mean_signal_strength, 
    avg(battery_level) as mean_battery_level 
    from IMEIdatasetname group by IMEI')
```

Comment: `options(gsubfn.engine = "R")` should not be needed on the Mac if you are using R 3.0.0 or later.   Add a `#` before the first line so its clear its not always needed.

Comment: @GGrothendieck Added comment to first line. I am using the latest R, but still needed to set options.

Comment: Do you have a custom build of R?  I don't have a Mac but I understand that tcltk has been included with the standard Mac distribution of R since 3.0.0.  I have fixed the first two lines.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but got the following error:
Error in sqliteSendQuery(conn, statement, bind.data) : 
  RAW() can only be applied to a 'raw', not a 'character'
In addition: Warning message:
In sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) :
  Closing result set with pending rows

Comment: Could you put up your code so we can see it? I think one of your columns may be a type that can't be used in sqldf (possibly POSIXlt). Alternatively, use the command str(IMEIdatasetname) to find the type of each column and post that here.